# How to open GeoJSON file from OpenLayers 4.5?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

My name.geojson file is in EPSG:3857 and I try to open it on OpenLayers but it didn't show. Which code should I use to open name.geojson file?

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
          <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
            <style>
              .map {
                height: 400px;
                width: 100%;
              }
            </style>
            <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <title>OpenLayers example</title>
          </head>
          <body>
           <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                layers: [
                  new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                  })
                ],
                view: new ol.View({
                  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
                  zoom: 2
                })
              });
            </script>
          </body>
</html>
```

My GeoJSON is like:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } }, "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PROV_NAME": "PHAYAO", "REGION": "เหนือ", "Length": 471901.950000, "Area": 6099882141.720000, "PROV_CODE": "56", "REG_CODE": "02", "PROV_NAMT": "พะเยา" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 11178637.241381312, 2240871.010733759 ], [ 11178705.330343476, 2240860.5557918623 ], [ 11178753.986649765, 2240860.1461515916 ],
```

Comment: Can you show the geoJson file your are trying to load ?

Comment: {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } }, "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
{ "PROV_NAME": "PHAYAO",  "REGION": "เหนือ", "Length": 471901.950000, 
 "Area": 6099882141.720000,
 "PROV_CODE": "56",
 "REG_CODE": "02",
 "PROV_NAMT": "พะเยา" },
 "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon",   "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 11178637.241381312, 2240871.010733759 ], [ 11178705.330343476, 2240860.5557918623 ], [ 11178753.986649765, 2240860.1461515916 ],

Comment: do u understand

Comment: Check the sample in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below example :

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>


   <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/fddba97a4d51953e5b5c8358d0f1fd48/raw/9f9c14fe49073e4dbaa1be5ace3aa5ce67837ee2/test2.json'
    }) 
    });


    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The GeoJson coordinates is **EPSG 3857**.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {

        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
            [-625570.6, 6465993.0],
            [-305006.9, 6696510.8],
            [-546330.2, 6768547.6],
            [-445478.6, 7053093.0],
            [-279794.0, 7056694.8],
            [-359034.5, 7337638.4],
            [-211359.0, 7485313.8],
            [62380.8,   6955843.3],
            [220861.7,  6909019.4],
            [91195.5,   6700112.6],
            [213658.1,  6682103.4],
            [-625570.6, 6465993.0]]]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: thx you very much !! i love u

Comment: @sdfkswadfgkdl welcome but please mark it as answer